# Modulo of modulo. Let $p,N$ be positive integers with $N$ divides $p$. Does for every integer $X$, $[X\pmod{N}]\pmod{p}=X\pmod{p}$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

> Let $p,N$ be positive integers with $N$ divides $p$. Does for every integer $X$, $[X\pmod{N}]\pmod{p}=X\pmod{p}$?

This question is similar to [1] - I consider it different due to $N$ now dividing $p$ instead.

I am trying to simplify the expression:
    $$\phi(n)=[(4n)*((4n)^{-1}\pmod{65537})]\pmod{65537*4*n}$$
where $\phi(n)$ is Euler's totient function, and I'm thinking of using the result above for simplifying the RHS.

[The particular example using 65537 I have derived using congruences on the RSA system and application of the CRT.]

Please state what the correct result is and why  it's correct.
[1][[Modulo arithmetic (modulo of modulo)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2106132/modulo-arithmetic-modulo-of-modulo])

Comment: No, but we have $[X\pmod{N}]\pmod{p}=X\pmod{N}$ (holds in general when $N\leq p$)

Comment: Why is that the case? Please explain

Comment: Using modulo, we get a number less than that, so when $N\le p$, $X\pmod{N}<N\le p$.

Comment: $X\pmod{N}$ is the rest from division of $X$ by $N$. Then $0\leq X\pmod{N}<N\leq p$ by definition. But then it's the same as the rest from division of $X\pmod{N}$ by $p$ by definition i. e. $[X\pmod{N}]\pmod{p}$.

Comment: Ok, thus the correct answer is $[X\pmod{N}]\pmod{p}=X\pmod{N}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

If $\,\gcd(4n,p) = 1\,$ then by CRT = Chinese Remainder Theorem (or [Easy CRT](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/20259/242)) we have

$$\begin{align} &x\equiv 0\pmod{4n}\\ &x\equiv 1\pmod{p}\end{align}\,\iff\, x\equiv 4n((4n)^{-1}\bmod p) \pmod{\!4np}$$

Or, expressed in operator form, using the [mod Distributive Law](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2059937/242)

$$  x\bmod 4np \,=\, 4n((4n)^{-1}\bmod p)$$

Generally there is no way to further simplify that other than computing the inverse.

The titled equation is not generally true, i.e. generally

$$ (x\bmod N)\bmod NK  \,\neq\, x\bmod NK$$

For example when $\,x = N\,$ it becomes $\, 0 \neq  N\bmod NK,\,$ true for all $K>1$ (and $N\neq 0)$

Comment: how about using $a^{p-2} \cong a^{-1} \pmod{p}$, so $(4n)^{p-2} \cong (4n)^{-1}$ - does this simplify the result?

Comment: @unseen_rider That combined with repeated squaring is one way to compute modular inverses, but usually it is more efficient to use the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242).

Comment: Ok, so does this mean that the above $4n[(4n)^{−1}(modp)]$ simplifies to $4n[(4n)^{p-2}(modp)]=(4n)^{p-1}(modp)$ ?

Comment: @unseen_rider No,  $\, x\equiv (4n)^{\large p-1}\!\pmod{\!4np}\,$ but that's not "simpler" - it has larger modulus $\,4np > p.\,$ The point of using $\, 4n((4n)^{-1}\bmod p)$ is that we have reduced the modulus from $\,4np\,$ to $\,p,\,$ which simplifies the computation (e.g. consider $\,p\,$ very small compared to $n).\,$ Ditto for $\,4n((4n)^{\large p-2}\!\bmod p)\,$ but, as I said, generally it is more efficient to compute the inverse via extended Euclidean vs. raising to power $\,p-2.\,$